# Instead of creating appropriate index query is taking large time however neo4 write is fast enough

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using `neo4j-community-3.5.3` server in a system having 64 GB RAM and 32 cores.

My database size is currently 160 GB and it is growing like 1.5GB every day. I keep 12 GB in page cache and 8GB in heap.

Apart from uniqueness constraint I also create indexes on some of my node properties. Since in the current `neo4j` version `lucene_native-1.0` indexing is deprecated I am using the default `native-btree-1.0`.

So the problem that I am facing is that my write performance is very good. But while reading the query result instead of querying using indexes result comes around 1 minute.

My index size is almost 21 GB. My database size is continuously growing but I am not getting the query performance as I was expected.

Please give me some healthier suggestion so that I can tune my query. Thanks in advance.

Here is a sample of my query **with indexing**, and some profiles:

```
PROFILE
OPTIONAL MATCH (u1:USER)<-[p:MENTIONS]-(tw:TWEET)<-[m:POST]-(u2:USER)
USING INDEX tw:TWEET(date)
WHERE tw.date='2019-03-03' AND u1.author_screen_name='xxx'
RETURN
  u1.author_screen_name as mentioned_author,
  u2.author_name as mentioned_by_author,
  count(*) AS weight
ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 20
```

[Query_profile1_using_indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NxfgD.png)

[Query_profile2_using_indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01s7v.png)

[Query_profile3_using_indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7drP.png)

And here is a query **without indexing**, and some profiles:

```
PROFILE
OPTIONAL MATCH (u1:USER)<-[p:MENTIONS]-(tw:TWEET)<-[m:POST]-(u2:USER)
WHERE tw.date='2019-03-03' AND u1.author_screen_name='xxx'
RETURN
  u1.author_screen_name as mentioned_author,
  u2.author_name as mentioned_by_author,
  count(*) AS weight
ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 20
```

[Query_profile1_without_using_indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWBBv.png)

[Query_profile2_without_using_indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BG7C.png)

[Query_profile3_without_using_indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70lz3.png)

Without using indexing query time taken is   880572 ms
Using indexing query time taken is  57674 ms  for the same query.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xhc2e.png

Comment: Can you expand all the boxes in your profile? Also, why are you saying "query result instead of querying using indexes" when you clearly *are* using indexes?

Comment: Please expand all elements of the query plan before you post it (click the double-down-arrows in the lower right corner of the result pane). Also, can you attach the plan if you don't use the `USING INDEX` hint?

Comment: @InverseFalcon.... I have expanded the profile for the same query one case using indexing and the other case without using indexing

Comment: @cybersam .... I have posted now the expanded profile info.Actually my problem is that though i have created indexes and query my db using those index still m not getting the performance that I was expected.So I want to know, m I doing doing something wrong in my query or otherwise do I need to change my server configuration to run query faster.

Answer (score 1):

In either case you're doing your projections at the same time as your aggregation, which isn't efficient. First of all, since there's only a single `u1`, project the author_screen_name for this at the beginning, while your cardinality is only at a single row.

Then after your match, do your aggregations, ordering and limiting, based upon the nodes themselves, and once your results are aggregated, THEN do the projections so you're doing a minimal amount of work; you don't want to do property access for a ton of rows that you're only going to discard when you get the limited result set:

```
MATCH (u1:USER)
WITH u1, u1.author_screen_name as mentioned_author
OPTIONAL MATCH ...
...
WITH mentioned_author, u2, count(*) AS weight 
ORDER BY weight DESC 
LIMIT 20
RETURN mentioned_author, u2.author_name as mentioned_by_author, weight
```

Comment: Following your suggestion I have changed my query but I have not got the better performance.I might doing something wrong in my query.Can you please provide me the complete query structure for the same above query for a particular date(any date) using the date as an index and for a particular author_screen_name(say @realDonaldTrump).I tried with different way but failed everytime.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The changes suggested should work with either query, I didn't supply the whole thing because you have two queries in your description. As mentioned this will save just a little, doing the projection a bit more efficiently, but I have the feeling most of the time is spent doing the expansion. With your current model there's no way around that. You could instead try encoding the date into the relationship type, that should narrow the selectivity of your expansions and avoid the need to do filtering on date properties.

Comment: See Max De Marzi's [blog on flight graph modeling](https://maxdemarzi.com/2017/05/24/flight-search-with-neo4j/) for more info on that. The core of the idea is that only traversing specific relationship types as a means of filtering is super efficient. But expanding out a ton of paths and filtering by property (or doing a separate index lookup, expansion, then a node hash join) isn't nearly as efficient.